# How to get the windows username automatically?

Tags: java, spring, angular, rest, typescript

I'm developing an intranet web portal for our company, using Angular 5, Java Spring and REST, JDBC, JSON, MS SQL Server. I need seamless authentication to my website for which I've developed a method using LDAP, which retrieves the required details using the user's usename. Now, my only task is to get the username from the user automatically. Please help me to proceed further. Thank You!!

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any attempts made

Comment: You can get client's Windows username through browser using [Waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle). To provide your js async (REST) clients with current user infomration you could use JWT.

Comment: I was told that the request from the user married the user name as well and it can be retrieved using a java class like HttpContext. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The current user's username is available through a system property:

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

That's the user running the Java process.

If you're looking for the user running the browser, then you can't get the OS username using JavaScript.

Comment: Not thorugh JavaScript.. okay.. any other way??